# Angular JS : Show get Json by value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down that changes the ID of a value. The value corresponds to the JSON object.

I'm having problems "searching" or "filtering" the JSON objects name(property) by using the ID.

Code for displaying the current station

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{ stations.name | station_id:2 }}</a>
```

Current stations

```
$scope.currentStation = 1;
//Fake data
$scope.stations = 
[
    {'name':'Station1', 'station_id':1,'featured_album':'1 Featured Album'},
    {'name':'Station2', 'station_id':2,'featured_album':'2 Featured Album'},
    {'name':'Station3', 'station_id':3,'featured_album':'3 Featured Album'}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all a filter is used to filter a collection and return the modified collection.

```
<div ng-repeat="station in stations | getById('2')">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{ stations.name }}</a>
</div>
```

You can then create a filter that get this value based on the Id. But that's not what you want, since you're not using an ng-repeat. You just want to get a single value out of your collection. I suggest you to create a function in your controller that does this job for you:

```
$scope.getStationById = function(id) {
    var parsedId = +id,
        foundStation;

    angular.forEach($scope.stations, function(station) {
        if(station.station_id === parsedId) {
            foundStation = station;
        }
    });

    return foundStation;
};
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkxatywa/)

or you can use the currentstation scope variable:

[**jsFiddle - update**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkxatywa/1/)

**Edit:** Maybe I'm wrong, if you want to show more than just the name, it's a good advice to avoid multiple iterations on the controller. With a filter you can limit this to one iteration. Your filter should give back a new collection with only one result:

```
app.filter('getById', function() {
        return function(coll, id) {
            var parsedId = +id,
                foundStation;

            angular.forEach(coll, function(station) {
                if(station.station_id === parsedId) {
                    foundStation = station;
                }
            });

            // Create array if station found otherwise return empty array
            return foundStation ? [foundStation] : [];        
        };
    });
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkxatywa/3/)

Comment: _a filter is used to filter a collection_ - No. Only the built-in filter filter operates on collections.